# actual and formal argue ment lists differ in length/ found: no arguments

Tags: java, methods

I have currently just started a beginner java class and have met a problem in my code that I have no idea how to solve. The idea behind the program was to use 3 methods outside of the main method to obtain the number of employees, find out the missed dates for each employee, and average the missing dates.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average
{
   int daysAbsent = 0;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int employees, daysAbsent, averageDays;
      noOfEmp();
      daysMissed();
      avgDaysAbsent();
   }
   public static int noOfEmp()
   {
      int employees;
      System.out.println("How many employees do you have? ");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      employees = keyboard.nextInt();

      return employees;
   }
   public static int daysMissed(int employees)
   {
   int daysAbsent, i;
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   for(i = 1; i == employees; i++)
   {
      System.out.println("How many days was Employee #" + i + " absent?");
      daysAbsent = keyboard.nextInt();
   }
   return daysAbsent;
}
public static float avgDaysAbsent(int employees, int daysAbsent)
{
   float averageDays;

   averageDays = (daysAbsent/employees);
   System.out.println("Your employees averaged " + averageDays + " days absent");

   return averageDays;
 }
}
```

When I tried the compile the code I recieved the errors that the line containing the daysMissed(); and the line with avgDaysAbsent(); has an error where the method cannot be applied to the given types, no argument found, and the actual and formal argument lists differ in length. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Your code has several other problems. All your methods return values, but when they are called in `main` it ignores the return values. Your `for` loop is broken; with `i == employees` the loop will run if and only if there is exactly 1 employee. If it worked, you would read an int for each employee, throwing them all away and keeping just the last one. You also create several `Scanner`s over `System.in`. I'm not sure if that's a bug or just a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the method `daysMissed()` without any argument, but it expects an int parameter.

Its signature is :

`public static int daysMissed(int employees)`

so you should call it with an int parameter - `daysMissed(someIntVariable)`

You have the same error with `avgDaysAbsent(int employees, int daysAbsent)`, which expects two ints but you pass it none.

I'm assuming what you meant to do is :

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int employees, daysAbsent, averageDays;
      employees = noOfEmp();
      daysAbsent= daysMissed(employees);
      averageDays = avgDaysAbsent(employees,daysAbsent);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int employees, daysAbsent, averageDays;
  employees = noOfEmp();
```

Eran's correction.

And don't you think that you'll have to **add** the entered values before you compute an average?

Comment: Is there a way to accumulate all the numbers in the method? I tried making a new variable but I don't really understand how to add them up. Would just add it in the for loop so it would be daysAbsent = daysAbsent + daysAbsent.